# How to find the nearest location using android studio and json?

Tags: android, json, location

I will add the Button "nearest", so if I click the button "nearest", maps will show 3 nearest location from user. anyone can help me? how to find the nearest location? i'm using android studio and database from mysql using json volley. i try to find a tutorial about this, but not found, if you have or find a tutorial about this, please give me a link. i'm newbie.
This is my coding Maps.java

```
private void initMap() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public boolean googleServicesAvailable() {
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "can't connect to play services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    getLokasi();

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
}

private void getLokasi() {

    String url = "http://sempatbimbel.esy.es/actions/jsontbimbel.php";
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    numData = response.length();
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "PARSE JSON");
                    latLng = new LatLng[numData];
                    markerD = new Boolean[numData];
                    id_bimbel = new int [numData];
                    foto = new String[numData];
                    namabimbel = new String[numData];
                    Alamat = new String[numData];
                    kecamatan = new String[numData];
                    latitude = new Double[numData];
                    longitude = new Double[numData];
                    kontak = new String[numData];
                    biaya = new String[numData];

                    for (int i = 0; i < numData; i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            id_bimbel[i] = data.getInt("id_bimbel");
                            latLng[i] = new LatLng(data.getDouble("latitude"), data.getDouble("longitude"));
                            foto[i] = data.getString("foto");
                            namabimbel[i] = data.getString("namabimbel");
                            Alamat[i] = data.getString("Alamat");
                            kecamatan[i] = data.getString("kecamatan");
                            latitude[i] = data.getDouble("latitude");
                            longitude[i] = data.getDouble("longitude");
                            kontak[i] = data.getString("kontak");
                            biaya[i] = data.getString("biaya");

                            markerD[i] = false;
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(latLng[i])
                                    .title(namabimbel[i])
                                    .snippet(Alamat[i])
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng[i], 12f));
                    }
                    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                            Log.d("DEBUG", "Marker Clicked");
                            for (int i=0; i<numData; i++){
                                if (marker.getTitle().equals(namabimbel[i])){
                                    if (markerD[i]){
                                        Log.d("DEBUG", "panggil activity");
                                        openDetailActivity(id_bimbel[i],foto[i],namabimbel[i],Alamat[i],kontak[i],biaya[i],kecamatan[i],latitude[i],longitude[i]);
                                        markerD[i]=false;
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("DEBUG", "show info");
                                        markerD[i] = true;
                                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tekan sekali lagi untuk melihat detail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); toast.show();
                                        TextView tv = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                                        if (tv != null)
                                            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                        toast.show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    markerD[i] = false;
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
                    } , new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Maps.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Error!");
                            builder.setMessage("No Internet Connection");
                            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Refresh", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    getLokasi();
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            alert.show();
                        }
                    });
                    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
                }

private void openDetailActivity (Integer id_bimbel, String foto,String namabimbel, String Alamat, String kontak, String biaya, String kecamatan, Double latitude, Double longitude )
{
    Intent i=new Intent(Maps.this, Detail.class);

    //Data
    i.putExtra("id_bimbel", id_bimbel);
    i.putExtra("foto",foto);
    i.putExtra("namabimbel",namabimbel);
    i.putExtra("Alamat",Alamat);
    i.putExtra("kontak",kontak);
    i.putExtra("biaya",biaya);
    i.putExtra("kecamatan",kecamatan);
    i.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
    i.putExtra("longitude",longitude);


    Maps.this.startActivity(i);

}
```

}